# How to found custom function in excel

Tags: excel, vba, function, excel-formula

I dont know if its a custom function or custom formula or whatever. Honestly I dont know much about excel at all.

I need to translate this formula/function to code, no biggie, I thought. But can't find it anywhere, I need to figure out the calculation.

[image]

At least I know

```
="Segment "&
```

Segment is a string, nothing weird and the ampersand concatenate the string with a function, but the:

```
Function!R15
```

I'm clueless here,

And if I "Step In" I get

```
SUM(K15:P15)
```

Those cell's are empty btw.

I'm starting to think that "Function" is a custom Visual Basic Function, but I'm  left clueless, here how to figure out the calculation.

Comment: It was a hidden sheet! :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than 1 sheet in a workbook, and you want to reference a cell in another sheet - you have to use the sheet name too.

So, if you wanted to add two cells together on different sheets, but they have thee same address - how will Excel know which sheet you mean?

`=A1+'Other Sheet'!A1`

This will add A1 on the active sheet, and A1 on the sheet called "Other Sheet"

In your example, `Function!R15` refers to the cell R15 on the sheet called "Function".

I imagine in that cell (R15) there is a formula of `=SUM(K15:P15)` which is why you're getting that upon evaluating.

Comment: I got two  sheet's, 1st named: SegmentID (2), and the other named Sheet1, which is empty.

Comment: Do you have any add-ins? Or perhaps it's a hidden sheet?

Comment: It was a hidden sheet! Thanks!